# Auto Suggest on Amazon Cloud Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, autocomplete, autosuggest, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to use amazon cloudsearch to implement search functionality.

It uses set of key:value pair to represent a document. A suggester can be defined that will give auto complete suggestions based on the values of a particular key. It searches documents whose values in the suggester field start with the specified query string—the beginning of the field must match the query string to be considered a match.

I have searched its [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/getting-suggestions.html). I want to enable auto complete suggestions also from a word present in the middle and not just at the start. Can i enable this on amazon cloudsearch?

Comment: switched to solr now as did not find a way to achieve it on cloudsearch. Now looking for a way to configure n-grams on its text fields in solr.

Comment: Refer here to configure auto complete with solr:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862609/how-to-get-suggestions-in-solr-5-3-0